# CRYSTAL REPORT USING Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, report

I'm using Visual studio 2008 to develop an application. I use Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, but before the report display, the user name and password are requested.
I want to know how to bypass the User name and Password?

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the server details and login credentials through code the user should not be prompted.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables ;

            cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables ;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-dynamic-login.htm